# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: events.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm fetching data using graphQL but wen I render in the page
it says **Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: events.map is not a function**

useState don't know if this correct?

const [events, setEvents] = useState < any > ([]);

```
const fetchEvents = async () => {
    const requestBody = {
      query: `
      query{
        events{
          _id
          title
          date
          price
          description
          creator {
            _id
            email
          }
        }
      }
      `
    };

    setLoading(true);
    await fetch(`http://localhost:8888/graphql`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    }).then(res => {
      if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
        throw new Error('Failed!');
      }
      return res.json();
    }).then(resData => {
      //console.log(resData);
      const events = resData.data.events;
      setEvents({ events: events })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

```
  {
   loading ? events.map((data: any, index: any) =>
    <p key={index}>{data.title}</p>
    )
    :
    <p>Loading</p>
   }
```

my console.log
[image]

Comment: Firstly, you are not updating the loading state after get the response from the api. Secondly, you are loading the component when `loading` is true. It should be other way around. Lastly, map works on an array not an object, make sure your event is an array. FYI {event: events} seems like an object :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `loading` to `false` once you receive the desired response. You should also access the `events` by using `events.events` (or better use `setEvents(events)`).

```
const fetchEvents = async () => {
const requestBody = {
  query: `
  query{
    events{
      _id
      title
      date
      price
      description
      creator {
        _id
        email
      }
    }
  }
  `
};

setLoading(true);
await fetch(`http://localhost:8888/graphql`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
}).then(res => {
  if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
    throw new Error('Failed!');
  }
  return res.json();
}).then(resData => {
  //console.log(resData);
  const events = resData.data.events;
  setEvents({ events: events });
  // CHECK NEXT LINE
  setLoading(false);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
}
```

Then you should change your React component to render the list only when `loading` is set to `false`. I also think (not sure cause you didn't submitted the full code) that you have to access the events using `events.events.map`

```
{!loading ? events.events.map((data: any, index: any) =>
<p key={index}>{data.title}</p>
)
:
<p>Loading</p>
}
```

Comment: same error... @cristi-nica

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in my code. Please check again. Also, I think it's better to use `setEvents(events)` instead of the way you're currently doing it.